# Error 2 when running the makefile of open-source code

Tags: makefile, open-source

So I'm trying to run the open-source code from [this research paper](http://pub.ist.ac.at/group_wojtan/projects/2013_Ando_HALSoTM/index.html), but I keep getting [make] Error 2. The makefile for the code was thankfully provided so I all I did was run the make command when I was in the folder that contained the makefile.

I'm new to all of this, I got everything from the internet, so I apologize if I'm a bit ignorant. I'm trying to learn, please be patient (:

```
QuantumHoneybees-MacBook-Pro:femflip2 Joe$ make
makeCompiling src/adaptive2.cpp ...
 In file included from src/adaptive2.cpp:13:
./src/kernel.h:16:20: warning: unused function 'smooth_kernel' [-Wunused-function]
    static FLOAT64 smooth_kernel( FLOAT64 r2, FLOAT64 h ) {
                   ^
In file included from src/adaptive2.cpp:15:
./src/util2.h:29:13: warning: unused function 'dump' [-Wunused-function]
static void dump( const char *format, ...) {
            ^
./src/util2.h:45:13: warning: unused function 'run' [-Wunused-function]
static void run( const char *format, ...) {
            ^
./src/util2.h:54:20: warning: unused function 'format_str' [-Wunused-function]
static const char *format_str( const char *format, ...) {
                   ^
./src/util2.h:65:13: warning: unused function 'is_nan' [-Wunused-function]
static bool is_nan(const double v) {
            ^
./src/util2.h:86:17: warning: unused function 'square' [-Wunused-function]
        static FLOAT64 square(FLOAT64 a) {
                       ^
./src/util2.h:120:17: warning: unused function 'getSeconds' [-Wunused-function]
        static FLOAT64 getSeconds() {
                       ^
./src/util2.h:142:15: warning: unused function 'stretchPosition' [-Wunused-function]
        static vec2d stretchPosition( const svd2 &svd, vec2d p, FLOAT64 min, FLOAT64 max, bool inverse=true ) {
                     ^
./src/util2.h:162:28: warning: unused function 'marchPoints' [-Wunused-function]
        static std::vector<vec2d> marchPoints( const std::vector<vec2d> &nodes, const std::vector<FLOAT64> &levelsets, bool fill=true ) {
                                  ^
./src/util2.h:180:17: warning: unused function 'computeVolume' [-Wunused-function]
        static FLOAT64 computeVolume( const std::vector<vec2d> points ) {
                       ^
./src/util2.h:192:17: warning: unused function 'distance' [-Wunused-function]
        static FLOAT64 distance( const vec2d &p0, const vec2d &p1, vec2d &p ) {
                       ^
./src/util2.h:222:17: warning: unused function 'detDelaunay' [-Wunused-function]
        static FLOAT64 detDelaunay( vec2d p0, vec2d p1, vec2d p2, vec2d p3 ) {
                       ^
src/adaptive2.cpp:53:13: warning: unused function 'sampleVelocity' [-Wunused-function]
static bool sampleVelocity( sorter2& sorter, vec2d pos, FLOAT64 dpx, const std::vector<particle2 *> &neighbors, vec2d &vel ) {
            ^
13 warnings generated.
Compiling src/ann/ANN.cpp ...
Compiling src/ann/bd_fix_rad_search.cpp ...
Compiling src/ann/bd_pr_search.cpp ...
Compiling src/ann/bd_search.cpp ...
Compiling src/ann/bd_tree.cpp ...
Compiling src/ann/brute.cpp ...
Compiling src/ann/kd_dump.cpp ...
src/ann/kd_dump.cpp:44:14: warning: unused variable 'EPSILON' [-Wunused-const-variable]
const double    EPSILON                 = 1E-5; // small number for float comparison
                ^
1 warning generated.
Compiling src/ann/kd_fix_rad_search.cpp ...
Compiling src/ann/kd_pr_search.cpp ...
Compiling src/ann/kd_search.cpp ...
Compiling src/ann/kd_split.cpp ...
Compiling src/ann/kd_tree.cpp ...
Compiling src/ann/kd_util.cpp ...
Compiling src/ann/perf.cpp ...
Compiling src/annsorter2.cpp ...
In file included from src/annsorter2.cpp:9:
In file included from ./src/annsorter2.h:10:
In file included from ./src/ann2.h:11:
./src/util2.h:29:13: warning: unused function 'dump' [-Wunused-function]
static void dump( const char *format, ...) {
            ^
./src/util2.h:45:13: warning: unused function 'run' [-Wunused-function]
static void run( const char *format, ...) {
            ^
./src/util2.h:54:20: warning: unused function 'format_str' [-Wunused-function]
static const char *format_str( const char *format, ...) {
                   ^
./src/util2.h:65:13: warning: unused function 'is_nan' [-Wunused-function]
static bool is_nan(const double v) {
            ^
./src/util2.h:86:17: warning: unused function 'square' [-Wunused-function]
        static FLOAT64 square(FLOAT64 a) {
                       ^
./src/util2.h:120:17: warning: unused function 'getSeconds' [-Wunused-function]
        static FLOAT64 getSeconds() {
                       ^
./src/util2.h:142:15: warning: unused function 'stretchPosition' [-Wunused-function]
        static vec2d stretchPosition( const svd2 &svd, vec2d p, FLOAT64 min, FLOAT64 max, bool inverse=true ) {
                     ^
./src/util2.h:162:28: warning: unused function 'marchPoints' [-Wunused-function]
        static std::vector<vec2d> marchPoints( const std::vector<vec2d> &nodes, const std::vector<FLOAT64> &levelsets, bool fill=true ) {
                                  ^
./src/util2.h:180:17: warning: unused function 'computeVolume' [-Wunused-function]
        static FLOAT64 computeVolume( const std::vector<vec2d> points ) {
                       ^
./src/util2.h:192:17: warning: unused function 'distance' [-Wunused-function]
        static FLOAT64 distance( const vec2d &p0, const vec2d &p1, vec2d &p ) {
                       ^
./src/util2.h:222:17: warning: unused function 'detDelaunay' [-Wunused-function]
        static FLOAT64 detDelaunay( vec2d p0, vec2d p1, vec2d p2, vec2d p3 ) {
                       ^

11 warnings generated.
make: *** [all] Error 2
QuantumHoneybees-MacBook-Pro:femflip2 Joe$ make
```

**Edit::** I've narrowed it down to the makefile in lines 36-44 there is something wrong with what is written. I unfortunately have zero experience with writing makefiles, so I don't know how to fix it. I tried messing around with some lines' indentation because some other threads seem to have that issue, but to no avail.

Answer (score 0):

There's a missing `include` in `fluid2.h`, `NULL` isn't defined.

Either invoke

```
make OPT="-Wall -Os -include cstddef"
```

Or add

```
#include <cstddef>
```

to the includes in `fluid2.h`.

---

It's quicker to just rewrite the terrible included makefile, try this:

```
CC       := g++
CPPFLAGS := -Isrc -Isrc/ann -Isrc/pcgsolver -MMD -MP
CXXFLAGS := -Wall -Os
LDFLAGS  := -framework OpenGL -framework GLUT

sources := $(wildcard src/*.cpp src/ann/*.cpp)
objects := $(sources:.cpp=.o)
deps    := $(objects:.o=.d)

flip2d: $(objects)
    $(LINK.o) $^ $(LDLIBS) -o $@

.PHONY: clean
clean: ; $(RM) $(objects) $(deps) flip2d

-include $(deps)
```

Comment: Nope... still didn't work when I added the cstddef library to the includes in fluid2.h.This is the error I got:  

`make[1]: Nothing to be done for 'depend'.`  
`make: *** [all] Error 2`

Comment: @QuantumHoneybees Unless you can provide where the error occurs it's not going to be much help, try deleting the `@` marks before the recipes in the makefile and try again, GCC should spit out one or more errors.

Comment: check my edit (: I was just typing it out! Also, I will try to do so.

Comment: @QuantumHoneybees The answer I posted works fine for me on OSX, what does `make -v` tell you?

Comment: Alright, there seems to be an issue with the `@make depend` part.

can you run me through how you ran the code?

I'm gonna try redownloading and starting from scratch

Comment: @QuantumHoneybees Also dump the output of `set`, you might be inadvertently overriding one or more of make's variables.

Comment: How would I do that? (This is all brand new to me, sorry)

Comment: Also, `make -v` returns this:

GNU Make 3.81
Copyright (C) 2006  Free Software Foundation, Inc.
This is free software; see the source for copying conditions.
There is NO warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A
PARTICULAR PURPOSE.

This program built for i386-apple-darwin11.3.0

Comment: @QuantumHoneybees Just type `set` in the shell, you can exclude any functions that come up after the variables, I'm only interested in the `ALL_CAPS=` stuff. Feel free to delete any personally identifiable info.

Comment: `_=run`
`__CF_USER_TEXT_ENCODING=0x1F5:0x0:0x0`

This is what I get after the lines of `ALL_CAPS=` stuff, and before the functions.

I ran` make OPT="-Wall -Os -include cstddef"` afterwards and it still gave me the same `make[1]: Nothing to be done for 'depend'.`
`make: *** [all] Error 2` Error

Comment: While looking through the `ALL_CAPS=` stuff, I found this line: `PATH=/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/opt/X11/bin:/Library/TeX/texbin`      Now, tex is a library I installed for my assignments, this shouldn't be popping up here. Am I doing something wrong? Should I have something installed/set up that I currently may not?

Comment: I just realized you wanted the ALL_CAPS= stuff, I must've misread that. It's been a long day. Here it is (part 1):

`BASH=/bin/bash`
`BASH_ARGC=()`
`BASH_ARGV=()`
`BASH_LINENO=()`
`BASH_REMATCH=([0]="2")`
`BASH_SOURCE=()`
`BASH_VERSINFO=([0]="3" [1]="2" [2]="57" [3]="1" [4]="release"` `[5]="x86_64-apple-darwin15")`
`BASH_VERSION='3.2.57(1)-release'`
`COLUMNS=150`
`DIRSTACK=()`
`DISPLAY=/private/tmp/com.apple.launchd.KLB2jqkoET/org.macosforge.xquartz:0`

Comment: (part 2) 

`EUID=501`
`GROUPS=()`
`HISTFILE=/Users/Joe/.bash_sessions/79F99DBD-BD20-4A18-B61D-5A760C1D4BDF.historynew`
`HISTFILESIZE=500`
`HISTSIZE=500`
`HOSTNAME=QH`
`HOSTTYPE=x86_64`
`IFS=$' \t\n'`
`LANG=en_US.UTF-8`
`LINES=41`
`LOGNAME=Joe`
`MACHTYPE=x86_64-apple-darwin15`
`MAILCHECK=60`
`OPTERR=1`
`OPTIND=1`
`OSTYPE=darwin15`
`PATH=/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/opt/X11/bin:/Library/TeX/texbin`
`PIPESTATUS=([0]="127")`
`PPID=6426`
`PROMPT_COMMAND=update_terminal_cwd`
`PS1='\h:\W \u\$ '`
`PS2='> '`
`PS4='+ '`

Comment: (part 3)

`PWD=/Users/Joe/Desktop/code/femflip2`
`SHELL=/bin/bash`
`SHELLOPTS=braceexpand:emacs:hashall:histexpand:history:interactive-comments:monitor`
`SHELL_SESSION_DID_INIT=1`
`SHELL_SESSION_DIR=/Users/J/.bash_sessions`
`SHELL_SESSION_FILE=/Users/J/.bash_sessions/79F99DBD-BD20-4A18-B61D-5A760C1D4BDF.session`
`SHELL_SESSION_HISTFILE=/Users/J/.bash_sessions/79F99DBD-BD20-4A18-B61D-5A760C1D4BDF.history`
`SHELL_SESSION_HISTFILE_NEW=/Users/J/.bash_sessions/79F99DBD-BD20-4A18-B61D-5A760C1D4BDF.historynew`
`SHELL_SESSION_HISTFILE_SHARED=/Users/Joe/.bash_history
SHELL_SESSION_HISTORY=1`

Comment: part 4

`SHELL_SESSION_TIMESTAMP_FILE=/Users/Joe/.bash_sessions/_expiration_check_timestamp`
`SHLVL=1`
`SSH_AUTH_SOCK=/private/tmp/com.apple.launchd.1Dg6A0SzMx/Listeners`
`TERM=xterm-256color`
`TERM_PROGRAM=Apple_Terminal`
`TERM_PROGRAM_VERSION=361.1`
`TERM_SESSION_ID=79F99DBD-BD20-4A18-B61D-5A760C1D4BDF`
`TMPDIR=/var/folders/db/bszlwnr57k14302m81bsqllw0000gn/T/`
`UID=501`
`XPC_FLAGS=0x0`
`XPC_SERVICE_NAME=0`
`_=shell`
`__CF_USER_TEXT_ENCODING=0x1F5:0x0:0x0`

Comment: @QuantumHoneybees Try the new solution, I have no idea what's going on :D